# How to change options with setOptions in DirectionsRenderer

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm changing options in a Google maps [`DirectionsRenderer`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRenderer) using `setOptions`. I can toggle the `draggable` option by just using `setOptions` but in order to toggle `suppressPolylines` and `suppressMarkers` and render it on the map I need an extra `directionsDisplay.setMap(map);`.

Why? (uncomment the line `//directionsDisplay.setMap(map);` to see this behavior)

```js
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
var time;

var pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5, 0.13);
var pointB = new google.maps.LatLng(60.17, 24.94);

function initialize() {

  var rendererOptions = {
      map: map,
      draggable: true
    }
    // Instantiate a directions service.
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);

  // Create a map and center it on pointA.
  var mapOptions = {
    center: pointA
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  calcRoute();
}

function calcRoute() {
  var request = {
    origin: pointA,
    destination: pointB,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      console.log("something went wrong: " + status);
    }
  });
};

function changeOption(el) {
  var options = {};
  options[el.id] = el.checked;
  directionsDisplay.setOptions(options);
  // without the next line suppressPolylines and suppressMarkers are not updated
  //directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#map {
  height: 280px;
  width: 50%;
}
section {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<section id="map"></section>
<section>

<input type="checkbox" id="suppressPolylines" onclick="changeOption(this)">suppressPolylines 
<p>
<input type="checkbox" id="draggable" onclick="changeOption(this)" checked>draggable
<p>
<input type="checkbox" id="suppressMarkers" onclick="changeOption(this)">suppressMarkers
</section>
```

Comment: in the documentation you may read for these options ***Suppress the rendering of .....***  , but nothing about removing of features that already have been rendered when you set the option. As long as it isn't documented you can't expect a specific behaviour.  When you call `setMap` after setting the options the directions will be re-rendered.

Comment: Ok, thanks now I get it. Changing options in the `DirectionsRenderer` does not affect objects that have already been rendered (such as polylines or markers)--to see the effect they need to be re-rendered (by calling `setMap`). Makes sense.

Comment: Just to clarify: as long as it isn't documented you can't expect a specific behaviour, the behaviour may change in the next API-version. For example when you click on a Marker to open a InfoWindow and the set `suppressInfoWindows` to `true`, the  already rendered InfoWindow will disappear

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```js
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
directionsDisplay.setOptions({
    map: map,
    dragable: true
});
```